# Read and Write TCP Streams

Tags: rust, tcp

I am working on an in memory on disk cache and am using TCP to send data between the client and server

Testing locally things seem to be working alright. I've written a small test client so I can easily talk to the server. When sending and receiving messages I prepend them with "{size}|", which is followed by the content of the message. What I'm asking is, am I on the right track so far? I've also started to play with switching over to Tokio.rs, using tokio_proto to handle the server side reads and writes. Is this a better/more stable approach.

Here is some of the code I have so far(the parts I think are relevant)

Server

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io;
use std::string::String;
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::thread;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

use rem::cache::Cache;
use rem::cache::CacheOperation;
use rem::error::*;
use rem::op;

pub fn launch(ip: String, port: String) {

    info!("Starting on {}:{}", ip, port);

    let listener: TcpListener = TcpListener::bind(format!("{}:{}", ip, port).as_str()).unwrap();

    let cache = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Cache::new()));

    loop {
        // accept connections and process them, spawning a new thread for each one
        for stream in listener.incoming() {
            let cache: Arc<Mutex<Cache>> = cache.clone();
            match stream {
                Ok(mut stream) => {
                    thread::spawn(move || {
                        info!("Incoming connection: {:?}", stream.peer_addr());
                        io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
                        loop {
                            let client_res = handle_client(&mut stream, &cache);
                            if client_res.is_err() {
                                error!("An error occured while handling a client connection: {}",
                                       client_res.unwrap_err());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                Err(e) => error!("Incoming connection failed. Error {}", e),
            }
        }
    }
}


fn handle_client(mut stream: &mut TcpStream, cache: &Arc<Mutex<Cache>>) -> Result<(), RemError> {
    let buf_str: String = try!(op::string_from_stream(stream));
    if buf_str.len() > 0 {
        let cache_op: CacheOperation = CacheOperation::new_from_string(&buf_str);

        debug!("cmds = {:?}, value = {}", cache_op.commands, cache_op.value);

        if cache_op.commands.len() > 0 {
            let prim_cmd: char = cache_op.commands[0];
            return match prim_cmd {
                'W' => op::write_stream_str_to_cache(cache_op.value, cache),
                'R' => op::read_value_from_cache(cache_op.value, cache, &mut stream),
                'D' => op::delete_value_from_cache(cache_op.value, cache),
                _ => Err(RemError::with_reason(format!("Invalid cache command {:?}", prim_cmd))),
            };
        }
    } else {
        panic!("Empty cache operation");
    }
    return Ok(());
}
```

Client

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io;
use std::string::String;
use std::vec::Vec;
use std::net::{TcpStream};
use std::mem;

use rem::op;
use rem::error::*;

pub fn launch(ip: String, port: String) {
    info!("Connection to {}:{}", ip, port);

    match TcpStream::connect(format!("{}:{}", ip, port).as_str()) {
        Ok(mut stream) => {
            loop {
                // Contine looping, executing any commands from the user
                let handle = io::stdin();
                for line_res in handle.lock().lines() {
                    let line: String = line_res.unwrap();
                    let args:Vec<String> = parse_input(line);
                    if args.len() > 0{
                        let arg_ref = args[0].as_ref();
                        match arg_ref {
                            "write" => {
                                if args.len() == 3 {
                                    match client_exec_write(&args[1], &args[2], &mut stream){
                                        Ok(_) => (),
                                        Err(why) => why.log()
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    error!("Write expects two arguments - key and value");
                                }
                            },
                            "read" => {
                                if args.len() == 2 {
                                    match client_exec_read(&args[1], &mut stream){
                                        Ok(_) => (),
                                        Err(why) => why.log()
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    error!("Read expects one argument - key");
                                }
                            },
                            "delete" => {
                                if args.len() == 2 {
                                    match client_exec_delete(&args[1], &mut stream){
                                        Ok(_) => (),
                                        Err(why) => why.log()
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    error!("Delete expects one argument - key");
                                }
                            }
                            _ => error!("Not a valid command")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Err(e) => {
            panic!("Failed to connect to server. Error '{}'", e);
        }
    }
}


/// Executres a write operation by parsing the client command and converting it to REM format
/// ex: write abc:def would be converted to 9|W$abc:def and sent to the REM server
fn client_exec_write(key:&String, val:&String, mut stream: &mut TcpStream)-> Result<(), RemError> {
    let sized_val = String::from(format!("W${}:{}", key, val));
    return op::write_str_to_stream_with_size(&mut stream, sized_val);
}

/// Executres a read operation by parsing the client command and converting it to REM format
/// ex: read abc:def would be converted to 5|R$abc and sent to the REM launch_server
/// The respone from the REM server is writen to stdout
/// If stdout::flush fail a warning will be logged
fn client_exec_read(key: &String, mut stream: &mut TcpStream)-> Result<(), RemError>{
    let cmd_val = String::from(format!("R${}", key));
    try!(op::write_str_to_stream_with_size(&mut stream, cmd_val));
    let val: String = try!(op::string_from_stream(&mut stream));
    println!("{}", val);
    try!(io::stdout().flush());
    return Ok(());
}

/// Executes a delete operation by parsing the client command and converting it to REM format
/// ex: delete abc would be converted to 5|D$abc and sent to the REM server
fn client_exec_delete(key: &String, mut stream: &mut TcpStream) -> Result<(), RemError>{
    let cmd_val = String::from(format!("D${}", key));
    return op::write_str_to_stream_with_size(&mut stream, cmd_val);
}

struct InputParser{
    args:Vec<String>,
    current:String,
    consumed_double_quote:bool,
    consumed_single_quote:bool
}

impl InputParser{

    /// Consumes a space charater taking quotes into consideration
    /// If the parser has consumed an opening quote then the space will be consumed as a character
    pub fn consume_space(&mut self){
        // If neither a single quote or a double quote has been consumed then its a new argument
        if !self.consumed_double_quote && !self.consumed_single_quote {
            self.push_current();
        }else{
            self.current.push(' ');
        }
    }

    /// Consumes a double quote, keeping track of whether it is an opening or cloing quote
    /// Takes single quotes into account when determening if the double quote is a delimiter or character
    pub fn consume_double_quote(&mut self){
        // If a single quote hasn't been consumed we're at the end or 
        // beginning of an argument in double quotes
        if  !self.consumed_single_quote {
            if self.consumed_double_quote{
                self.push_current();
            }
            // Flip the value so we know the sate for the next double quote that is consumed
            self.consumed_double_quote = !self.consumed_double_quote;
        }else{
            // If we're in double quotes just treat the double quote as a regular character 
            self.current.push('"');
        }
    }

    /// Consumes a single quote, keeping track of whether it is an opening or cloing quote
    /// Takes double quotes into account when determening if the single quote is a delimiter or character
    pub fn consume_single_quote(&mut self){
         // If a double quote hasn't been consumed we're at the end or 
        // beginning of an argument in single quotes
         if !self.consumed_double_quote {
            if self.consumed_single_quote{
                self.push_current();
            }
            // Flip the value so we know the sate for the next single quote that is consumed
            self.consumed_single_quote = !self.consumed_single_quote;
        }else{
            // If we're in double quotes just treat the single quote as a regular character 
            self.current.push('\'');
        }
    }

    /// Adds the character onto the current argument
    pub fn consume_char(&mut self, c:char){
        self.current.push(c);
    }

    /// To be called when everything has been parsed
    pub fn end(&mut self){
        self.push_current();
    }

    /// Pushes the current string into the list of args
    /// If the length of current is 0 no actions are performed
    pub fn push_current(&mut self){
        if self.current.len() > 0 {
            let arg = mem::replace(&mut self.current, String::new());
            self.args.push(arg);
        }
    }

}

/// Parses the arguments out of an input string taking quotes and spaces into consideration
pub fn parse_input(input: String) -> Vec<String>{
    let mut parser = InputParser{
        args:Vec::new(),
        current:String::new(),
        consumed_double_quote:false,
        consumed_single_quote:false
    };    
    for c in input.chars(){
        match c {
            '"'  => parser.consume_double_quote(),
            ' '  => parser.consume_space(),
            '\'' => parser.consume_single_quote(), 
            _    => parser.consume_char(c)
        }
    }
    parser.end();

    return parser.args;
}
```

Operations

````
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::string::String;
use std::vec::Vec;
use std::net::{TcpStream};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

use rem::cache::Cache;
use rem::error::*;

pub fn read_value_from_cache(key: String,
                         cache_mtx: &Arc<Mutex<Cache>>,
                         mut stream: &mut TcpStream)
                         -> Result<(), RemError> {
    let cache = cache_mtx.lock().unwrap();
    let cache_opt: Option<Box<Vec<u8>>> = try!(cache.read_item(key));
    match cache_opt {
        Some(boxed_val) => {
            let val: Vec<u8> = *boxed_val;
            debug!("Writing to stream {:?}", val);
            try!(write_str_to_stream_with_size(&mut stream, String::from_utf8(val).unwrap()));
            return Ok(());
        }
        None => {
            try!(write_str_to_stream_with_size(&mut stream, String::from("Invalid Key")));
            return Err(RemError::with_reason(String::from("Could not read from cache")));
        }
    }
}

/// Parses a TCP input stream and extracts the data
/// Allocates a 64 byte buffer which is used to read the input info from the stream
/// The expected format is ```{size}|{content}```
/// Ex. ```5|W$a:b```
pub fn string_from_stream(stream: &mut TcpStream) -> Result<String, RemError> {
    //Read in the first 54 bytes of the stram
    try!(stream.set_nodelay(true));
    let mut buf_arr: [u8; 64] = [0; 64];
    try!(stream.read(&mut buf_arr));
    // Parse the message size
    let mut size_str = String::new();
    let mut buf_size: usize = 0;
    for i in 0..64 {
        buf_size += 1;
        if buf_arr[i] == '|' as u8 {
            break;
        }
        size_str.push(buf_arr[i as usize] as char);
    }

    // Convert the size string to a usize so it can be used to drain the buffer
    let upper_idx: usize = try!(size_str.parse::<i32>()) as usize;
    let mut buf_temp: Vec<u8> = buf_arr.to_vec();
    // Create a new buffer using the parsed indicies
    let buf: Vec<u8> = buf_temp.drain(buf_size..upper_idx + buf_size).collect();

    stream.flush().unwrap();

    // Return the value as a string
    let buf_str: String = String::from_utf8(buf).unwrap();
    return Ok(buf_str);
}

pub fn write_stream_str_to_cache(stream_str: String,
                             cache_mtx: &Arc<Mutex<Cache>>)
                             -> Result<(), RemError> {
    let mut key: String = String::new();
    let mut val: String = String::new();
    let mut idx = 0;
    let chars_iter = stream_str.chars();
    for c in chars_iter {
        idx += 1;
        if c == ':' {
            val = String::from(&stream_str[idx..]);
            break;
        }
        key.push(c);
    }
    let bytes = val.into_bytes();
    let mut cache = cache_mtx.lock().unwrap();
    return cache.cache_item(key, bytes);
}

pub fn delete_value_from_cache(key: String, cache_mtx: &Arc<Mutex<Cache>>) -> Result<(), RemError> {
    let mut cache = cache_mtx.lock().unwrap();
    return cache.delete_item(key);
}

pub fn write_str_to_stream_with_size(stream: &mut TcpStream, value: String) -> Result<(), RemError> {
    let sized_val = String::from(format!("{}|{}", value.len(), value));
    try!(stream.write(String::from(sized_val).as_bytes()));
    try!(stream.flush());
    return Ok(());
}
````

[The rest of the code](https://github.com/RyanBluth/rem/tree/master/src/rem)